# Sharing MS-Access 2003 application

Tags: ms-access, sharing, citrix

We are using a legacy MS-Access 2003 application.Currently, we are sharing through CITRIX; which is causing issues almost everyday.If we bypass CITRIX and access through drive no issue. **What is the best option to share MS-Access 2003 application among multiple users?**

Answer (score 0):

One of the best and most reliability ways to share an access application is to use Terminal services or in your case CITRIX.

Every book, article, IT professional who has any competency and ANY ability and ANY knowledge about Access will tell you that using Citrix for users to consume Access is the MOST reliable and robust choice in the industry you can make.

So if you having troubles, first up is a round of firing the group of incompetent people that clearly don’t know what they are doing.

Next up:
Each user that logs into their remote Citrix desktop needs to have a copy of the Access application (that is the front end part). And that front end part should be a compiled accDE, or in the case of Access 2003, then an mde.

So like 99% of other applications, you have two parts:
The application part (code, forms, the UI)

The data file part.

Remember, Access is the developer’s tool here. You are using it to create software. That resulting software has to be deployed to each user.

So as long as each user when they log into that remote desktop has their own copy of the application part (the mde front end part), then with Citrix you have likely one of the most robust and reliable setups money can buy. Even better is accidental network drops etc. will not drop or damage the Access application since each user is in fact consuming a remote desktop anyway.

So the best, top industry rated approach and most reliable setup is to use terminal services, or Citrix. However this assumes that the database has the two parts, and that multiple users NEVER are allowed into the same copy of the application (you MUST install and provide a separate copy for each remote user’s session. Place that mde in user “appdata” folder, or some place in my documents or whatever.

And even for the case when deploying Access to a standard office network say for on-site and “non” Citrix users? Then again each work station receives and must have their own copy of the front end mde, or so called application part.

Moving from deploying the access front end to each desktop does NOT change when you adopt CITRIX or Terminal services. In these cases, since everything remains on the server, then of course the Access front end is not deployed to the client station, but you MUST still ensure that each CITRIX user with their own sessions has their own copy of the front end mde. NEVER EVER in ANY case allow multiple users into a single copy of the application, but ALWAYS provide each logged on user a separate copy of the mde front end application.

Adopting the above approach should provide 10 to 15 year long periods without any issues or failures.

And the reverse is also true! Do not deploy and run Access with multiple users into a single copy of the application (mde). You can’t do this because if one user has some issue, then that front end can be damaged or even just setting a filter for a form or whatever can THEN effect other users.

So each user, regardless of CITRIX, Terminal Services, or just basic users that are “on location” and don’t use CITRIX – in VERY CASE you MUST provide a separate mde copy. So while in theory you have multiple users on the one CITRIX server, each of those users will have their own my documents and folders etc. And in one of those folders you provide that copy of the front end mde file.

As long as you have a split application, and don’t allow multiple users into a single same copy of the front end, then you have years and years of trouble free operation. And adopting CITRIX and/or Terminal services will in every use case I am aware of improvise this reliability even further.

Comment: Thank you Albert. Do we need to install MS-Access in the client computer?

Comment: No, you can use a iPhone, smartphone, Linux desktop, Apple desktop, or a iPad to consume the application. This technology is the same as remote desktop, or say goto my pc. Citrix means you are only sending mouse clicks and the screen to the  other end - no application install is required except for a RDP client. You can also adopt a Citrix/RDP bridge to HTML. If you adopt such a bridge, then your application will run on any device with a browser as 100% web based - and you don't have to modify the original application at all.

Comment: I got an error "Microsoft Office Access was unable to create an MDE database"

Comment: a rather different question - BEFORE you attempt to create a mde, you need to first in VBA go debug->compile and ensure no errors exist in your code. (during a typical day - you while coding likely use that compile option 100's of times).